# python need a program to uppercase what is inserted (with def function)

Tags: python

As the title says, for some reason the shell ignores the def function and does not uppercase the slogan.

```
number = int(input("how many times is the slogan displayed?: "))
entry = input("slogan:")

def banner(entry):
    entry = entry.upper()
    return(banner)

for i in range(number):
    print(entry)
```

Comment: You never call the function

Comment: You don't call the function and your function should also return entry instead of returning itself.

Comment: You have many problems here , I suggest you read a Doc first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your entire code? If so, you never call the function banner. You also return the function itself, which is recursive.

You would need to do something like:

```
number = int(input("how many times is the slogan displayed?: "))
entry = input("slogan:")

def banner(entry):
    entryUp = entry.upper()
    return entryUp

for i in range(number):
    print(banner(entry))
```

Banner cannot be used if you never request it's use.